# Why process.env.myvariable not working in nextjs typescript project type

Tags: typescript, next.js

I created a file named: .env.local in a root of my own project

and place into it a variable called WEBSOCKET_VARIABLE=THIS_IS_TEXT

But when I want to access it by : process.env.WEBSOCKET_VARIABLE , it can't find anything.

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: when adding a .env variable always make sure to kill the ongoing process and relaunch the application or it wont work

Comment: Im doing this but it wont work at all

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the environment variables in the browser, then you need to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

From the docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Im doing this but it wont work at all